# How can I do binding in another binding in XML View in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a binding for an attribute and I need to do another binding inside of the first binding:

```
<Text text="{ path:'myOdataModel>DefaultValidTo', 
              type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', 
              formatOptions: { source : { pattern : 'timestamp' }, 
              pattern: '\{myViewModel>/datePatern}' }
             }"/>
```

Actually I want to read the value of the `pattern` from my `viewModel` in run time based on the preferences of the user.

But it seems it is not possible to do binding inside another binding in `SAPUI5`.
Does anyone have any idea that how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through a formatter :

bind your text to the 2 model you need :

```
<Text
  text="{
    parts: [
      'myOdataModel>DefaultValidTo', 
      'myViewModel>/datePatern'
    ],
    formatter: '*.formatter.formatterxxxx*'
  }" />
```

then implement the adequate formatter function that will take two parameters

```
function formatterxxxx(<data from myOdataModel>DefaultValidTo>, <data from myViewModel>/datePatern>) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: For me it seems a good solution. But do you have any official evidences that shows it totally is not possible via XML view and something similar to my approach?

Comment: sure thing is 'text.formatOptions.pattern is NOT a property from a managedobject, and cannot be bind. the only binding entry there is on 'text' :)

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari It's the same issue as binding syntax not being supported on filter values (See https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130#issuecomment-320278250). Binding info objects are just **plain objects** without any metadata in contrast to ManagedObject which supports all types of binding.